# 1366 Incorrect string value исправить через миграции?

Tags: mysql, yii2

Появилась проблема, при сохранении в базу текста(кириллицей) вылетает ошибка **1366 Incorrect string value .**

В конфигах базы данных **Yii2** установлено **'charset' => 'utf8'.**

Вопрос, как исправить это с помощью миграций?

Comment: А у вас есть доступ к конфигу базы ?
Если да то пропишите в блоке  [mysqld] следующие строки
character-set-server=utf8
default-character-set=utf8

http://www.sql.ru/forum/636067/problema-s-utf8-teryautsya-kirillicheskie-bukvy-error-1366

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно в миграции добавить:

```
$this->alterColumn(
    'table.name',
    'table.column',
    $this->string()->append('CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL')
);
```